# Want to change the query url in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a link like this http://example.com/doctor/?doctor=demo,

Now i am getting the doctor name by this

```
$doctor_login = get_query_var( 'doctor' );
```

But i want the same with this url http://example.com/doctor/demo. It means i want to remove or change the url in the page when i click in the link.

Thank you

Comment: is ` http://example.com/doctor/` a page ? if so this link may help you 
http://www.rlmseo.com/blog/passing-get-query-string-parameters-in-wordpress-url/

Comment: This forbidden page.